# If value in certain cell equals "Certain Text" echo "Text"

Tags: php, database, if-statement, row

I'm trying to get this to echo a warning message when the cell contains a certain text like "0" or "N/A". It would work when there was no value entered in the first place, but I can't get it to echo when there is already a certain value. Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
<?php
                $listing = "$_POST[listing]";

                $sql = "SELECT open_house_attended FROM property_flyers WHERE street_property = '$listing' ";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);

                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    // output data of each row
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "</span><span class='report_bignumber'><br>".  $row["open_house_attended"]."</span>";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "<br> ". $noresults . "</span>";
                }

            ?>
```

Comment: You need to put an if() inside the while() loop to check for the specific value and echo one thing or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a little regex -

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // output data of each row
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      preg_match(trim($row["open_house_attended"]), '/[0]|[N\/A]/', $matches); // try to match '0' or 'N/A'
      if(count($matches) == 0) { // do we have matches?
          echo "</span><span class='report_bignumber'><br>".  $row["open_house_attended"]."</span>";
      } else {
           echo "<br> ". $noresults . "</span>";
      }
   }
}
?>
```

Or you can go a little more directly -

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // output data of each row
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $ohCount = $row["open_house_attended"];
      if(( $ohCount != '0') && ($ohCount != 'N/A')) { // do we have matches?
          echo "</span><span class='report_bignumber'><br>".  $ohCount ."</span>";
      } else {
           echo "<br> ". $noresults . "</span>";
      }
   }
}
?>
```

[`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: Didn't work for me. <?php
    $listing = "$_POST[listing]";

    $sql = "SELECT open_house_attended FROM property_flyers WHERE street_property = '$listing' ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $ohCount = $row["open_house_attended"];
      if(( $ohCount != '0') && ($ohCount != 'N/A')) { // do we have matches?
       echo "</span><span class='report_bignumber'><br>".  $ohCount ."</span>";
      } else {
        echo "<br> ". $noresults . "</span>";
      }
    }
    ?>

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments, they are virtually impossible to read. What do you mean by "didn't work for me"?

Comment: The code that you posted in the comments @themurphyteammarketing is missing some curly brackets. Please see the updated answer. You should have error checking on to make sure you see any syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT open_house_attended FROM property_flyers WHERE street_property = '$listing' AND open_house_attended NOT IN ('0', 'N/A')";
```

use NOT IN and a list of values to reject.  It's one option anyway.  The preg match option works as well, just it asks php to do the work and this asks sql to do it.

Comment: This would only list the records where something occurred while the OP would like a set including those that have no data. In that case the OP will show `$noresults` to the user.

Comment: good point, in that use case checking in php is the way to go.  up voted your answer.